The Buddha and singling out groups of people
What lesson did the Buddha teach concerning the singling-out of a group in society based on their perceived transgressions?

Birds of a feather flock together.
The idea in Buddhism is like attracts like.
The bad associate with the bad, the good with the good, the wise with the wise, the learned with the learned, the evil with the evil.
Because of this we need to be careful with our associations, our teachers and our guides, and make sure that they are Noble and taking us in the right direction towards higher determination, Maga, Pala and Nibbana (if we are Buddhist).
Lord Buddhas focus is on individual practice, Buddhas only point the way.
If you look at the past lives of the Buddhas, you can see how beings follow associations by groups (ie the Sakayan Clan would all be one species of animal in a past life of the Buddha). Also you can see the defilents that had to be overcome by the great disciples on their path to purity and parami.
These beings associated with each other over the past countless aeons by determination.
Secondly, Lord Buddha would only teach out of compassion to those who he could help. He would not speak to a non believer in the same way he would one on the Path. Sometimes he could see that he could help a being.
Each being has different spiritual accumulation, and Buddhas have the power of  knowing where a being is coming from, and how to know how to help them (if He can).
He would put His mind into a special attainment and look out into the world and see who he could help that day.
One good example is the story of Aṅgulimāla.
See the story of Aṅgulimāla as a Yakka in a past life of the Buddha, to see how his association lead him to being a disciple of Lord Buddha in his final life.
While this is not strictly about groups of society, it is speaking about causes for affinity in relation to the Buddhistic outlook.
SN 14:14 (listed here for study purposes; copyright BB, wisdom pub)

"At Sāvatthı̄. “Bhikkhus, it is by way of elements that beings come
together and unite. Those of an inferior disposition come together and
unite with those of an inferior disposition; those of a good
disposition come together and unite with those of a good disposition.
In the past, by way of elements, beings came together and united….
In the future, too, by way of elements, beings will come together and
unite…. Now too, at present, by way of elements, beings come together
and unite. Those of an inferior disposition come together and unite
with those of an inferior disposition; those of a good disposition
come together and unite with those of a good disposition.”

The Birds of the Feather quote actually comes from a past life of the Buddha; 158. Suhanu-Jātaka

"Birds of a feather flock together: Chestnut and Strongjaw both agree:
In scope and aim both are the same--there is no difference I can see."
"Both savage are, and vicious both; both always bite their
tether; So sin with sin, and vice with vice, must e’en agree
together."


Venerable Bhikkhu. SN 14,15 appears related to your answer: https://daily.readingfaithfully.org/sn-14-15-cankamasutta-walking-together/

Greetings @DhammaDhatu, Yes that was one I was thinking of, very good, Anumodana. Though I do prefer Wisdom Publication translation as it is a more direct translation even though it is not free.

One sutta suggests that if he would try one thing to train someone, and then another, and if nothing seems to work then he would cut them of from his training.
But IMO he singled out or identified behaviours, not people -- i.e. "This is good behaviour, this is bad behaviour", more than, "These are good people and these are bad people".

The Buddha taught beings are subject to their kamma when they commit transgressions. This operates via the law of kamma therefore the Buddha himself didn't spend most of his time singling-out an immoral group in society. What is important to understand is no groups are exempt from the laws of kamma.
I would guess in the Buddha's time, society was far less diverse than today and that the vast majority of people in society lived by religious precepts.

In the period of Buddha there were groups like Brahmins who disagreed with Buddha but he never singled them out. He suggested keeping calm and compassion and having reasonable mind during debates. There should be no anger or hatred. There is ignorance so everyone should be treated with compassion.
